# jqDock menu active state not resumed after mouseover

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, menu

I am using the jqDock plugin to build a dock menu with jquery. http://www.wizzud.com/jqDock/

There is one option to pass the "active" menu item index. The active state exists on page load but it doesn't work after mouseover the menu again.

Any suggestions to make this sample code working with "Active" state resume functionality.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.jqDock.min.js'></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  // set up the options to be used for jqDock...
  var dockOptions =
      { align: 'top' // horizontal menu, with expansion DOWN from a fixed TOP edge
  , size: 60 //increase 'at rest' size to 60px
  , labels: false //add labels
  , active: $('#menu a.active').index() //set the initially active item
  , onReady: function(){
      $(this).removeClass('hideThis'); //need to show the dock myself
      //return false; //leaves the dock asleep and requiring a 'nudge'!
    }
  }
  //and get $('#menu')...
, Menu = $('#menu');

  //replace my default click handler with a 'active' toggler...
  Menu.children().unbind('click').click(function(){
  //Note: I've set it so that you can only nudge the 'active' item...
  if($(this).filter('.active').removeClass('active').length){
    Menu.jqDock('nudge'); //wake or thaw the dock
  }else if(!$('.active', Menu).length){
    Menu.trigger('dockfreeze'); //freeze the dock
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
  this.blur();
  return false;
}).end()
// ...and apply jqDock...
.jqdock(dockOptions);
});
</script>
<style type="text\css"></style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='page'>
  <div id='menu' class='hideThis'>
    <a href='#'><img src='Addressbook.png' title='Downloads' alt='' /></a>
    <a href='#'><img src='DVD-Player.png' title='Websites' alt='' /></a>
    <a href='#' class='active'><img src='eMail.png' title='Users' alt='' /></a>
    <a href='#'><img src='Instant_Messaging.png' title='Security' alt='' /></a>
    <a href='#'><img src='Safari.png' title='System' alt='' /></a>
    <a href='#'><img src='Terminal.png' title='System' alt='' /></a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The only aspect i came to know is "jqDock" is initialized only once. it can not be re-initialized with different parameters again & again.

still no luck  :(

Answer (score 0):

In http://www.wizzud.com/jqdock/faqs/, number 27 attempts to explain the difficulty of maintaining an 'active' item. It also says that v1.6+ provides the means for a possible work-around, but that implementation is down to the builder.

You could try binding a mouseleave to the div.jqDock, that runs the jqdock 'expand' command on the a.active item? eg...

```
options.onReady = function(){
    $('#menu').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find('a.active img').jqdock('expand').end().jqdock('nudge');
    });
}
```

NB: the additional 'nudge' depends on wether you want to leave the Dock 'asleep' or not.

Personally, for the reasons stated in the FAQ referenced above, I would consider distinguishing the currently 'active' item by means of a style (like the green border in the example quoted) in preference having it 'expanded'. As warned in the documentation, using the 'active' option can (does!) produce nasty 'jump' effects.